# how to remove extra data point from x-axis in highcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

i am plotting data in highcharts for particular id's, but on x-axis showing extra data points, i only want specific data on x-axis ,i don't know how to remove extra data points. Please help. Thank You.
[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FXxH.png)

Comment: Without showing your code, nothing helps. What did your tried so far will help further to solve.

Comment: Please reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor.

Comment: Here is fiddle for that :https://jsfiddle.net/w07Lheam/1/

Comment: i only want those id's that I am using in my data and x axis categories to display to on x-axis

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I've created fiddle to reproduce  issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your data and provide x value as a string to make it work.

```
const parsedData = initialSeries.map(s => ({
    name: s.name,
    data: s.data.map(d => [d[0].toString(), d[1]])
}));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d9cmqbsp/